# Hide .jsp extension in Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat

How can I hide the.jsp extension in Tomcat 9?
I would like to use "/store" instead of "/store.jsp".
And how can I achieve this without mapping every single jsp?

Comment: 2nd: its time to use framework. In my opinion direct for JSP programmer is "action based framework", google. I give no recommendation, use component based Wicket & Vaadin

Comment: one possibility: take a look at tuckey url rewrite

Answer (score 1):

As of Tomcat 8 Url rewriting is a built-in feature.

First include the `RewriteValve` in the Context:

```
<Context [...]>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

Then in `WEB-INF` create a file `rewrite.config` containing the rewrite rules. They'll look familiar if you worked with Apache HTTP server. Here is a simple example adding '.jsp' after the url:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/(css|img|js).*)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /$1.jsp
```

I've put in a RewriteCond to exclude certain directories from rewriting, but this is not essential to demonstrate the concept.

Full documentation can be found at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html